# @ConfigurationProperties not setting values to fields on Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

Following the [Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot), I can't make the code works. The field is not be populated. I've created a simple Spring project and configure like the tutorial and tested using a @Scheduled function but is gotting a null value when access the field.

SpringBoot version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'

**Build.gradle dependencies**

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '1.2.1.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
}
```

**ConfgProperties**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
public class ConfgProperties {

    private String hostName;
    private int port;
    private String from;

    public String getHostName() {
        return hostName;
    }

    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
mail:
  hostname: host@mail.com
  port: 9000
  from: mailer@mail.com
```

**Scheduled**

```
ConfgProperties p;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
private void schedule() {
    LOGGER.info("P: {}", p.getFrom()); // NULL HERE
}
```

Main application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SpringDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Null exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sample.springdemo.job.JobTest.schedule(JobTest.java:30) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
```

Comment: have you miss the `@Configuration` on the class?

Comment: How do you inject ConfgProperties p; ? I can't see a constructor or @Autowired

Comment: Note also that Spring provides built-in support for mail; you seem to be reinventing it.

Comment: Solved with `@Configuration` and `@Autowired`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve via two ways. Would prefer the first option

1. We use @Configuration so that Spring creates a Spring bean in the application context.

```java
    @Configuration 
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
    public class ConfgProperties {
    
        private String hostName;
        private int port;
        private String from;
```

2. Define property name as below

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfgProperties.class)
    public class SpringDemoApplication {
```

Comment: Rather than `@Configuration`, you should use `@Component`. `@Configuration` is a specialization of `@Component` that is intended for defining beans via `@Bean` methods.